# How do I preform 'lookahead' in an OCaml lexer / how do I rollback a lexeme?

Tags: parsing, ocaml, lr-grammar, ocamllex, menhir

Well, I'm writing my first parser, in OCaml, and I immediately somehow managed to make one with an infinite-loop.

Of particular note, I'm trying to lex identifiers according to the rules of the Scheme specification (I have no idea what I'm doing, obviously) — and there's some language in there about identifiers requiring that they are followed by a delimiter. My approach, right now, is to have a `delimited_identifier` regex that includes one of the `delimiter` characters, that *should not be consumed* by the main lexer … and then once that's been matched, the reading of that lexeme is reverted by `Sedlexing.rollback` (well, [my wrapper thereof](https://github.com/ELLIOTTCABLE/ocameel/blob/e29078f5/lib/LexBuffer.ml#L72-L76)), before being passed to a sublexer that *only* eats the actual identifier, hopefully leaving the delimiter in the buffer to be eaten as a different lexeme by the parent lexer.

I'm using [Menhir](https://gitlab.inria.fr/fpottier/menhir#readme) and [Sedlex](https://github.com/alainfrisch/sedlex), mostly synthesizing the examples from [@smolkaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869927/smolkaj)'s [`ocaml-parsing`](https://github.com/smolkaj/ocaml-parsing) example-repo and [RWO's parsing chapter](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/16-parsing-with-ocamllex-and-menhir.html); here's the simplest reduction of my current [parser](https://github.com/ELLIOTTCABLE/ocameel/blob/e29078f5/lib/ParserAutomaton.mly) and [lexer](https://github.com/ELLIOTTCABLE/ocameel/blob/e29078f5/lib/Lexer.sedlex.body.ml):

```
%token LPAR RPAR LVEC APOS TICK COMMA COMMA_AT DQUO SEMI EOF
%token <string> IDENTIFIER
(* %token <bool> BOOL *)
(* %token <int> NUM10 *)
(* %token <string> STREL *)

%start <Parser.AST.t> program

%%

program:
  | p = list(expression); EOF { p }
  ;

expression:
  | i = IDENTIFIER { Parser.AST.Atom i }

%%
```

… and …

```
(** Regular expressions *)
let newline = [%sedlex.regexp? '\r' | '\n' | "\r\n" ]
let whitespace = [%sedlex.regexp? ' ' | newline ]
let delimiter = [%sedlex.regexp? eof | whitespace | '(' | ')' | '"' | ';' ]

let digit = [%sedlex.regexp? '0'..'9']
let letter = [%sedlex.regexp? 'A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z']

let special_initial = [%sedlex.regexp?
   '!' | '$' | '%' | '&' | '*' | '/' | ':' | '<' | '=' | '>' | '?' | '^' | '_' | '~' ]
let initial = [%sedlex.regexp? letter | special_initial ]

let special_subsequent = [%sedlex.regexp? '+' | '-' | '.' | '@' ]
let subsequent = [%sedlex.regexp? initial | digit | special_subsequent ]

let peculiar_identifier = [%sedlex.regexp? '+' | '-' | "..." ]
let identifier = [%sedlex.regexp? initial, Star subsequent | peculiar_identifier ]
let delimited_identifier = [%sedlex.regexp? identifier, delimiter ]


(** Swallow whitespace and comments. *)
let rec swallow_atmosphere buf =
   match%sedlex buf with
   | Plus whitespace -> swallow_atmosphere buf
   | ";" -> swallow_comment buf
   | _ -> ()

and swallow_comment buf =
   match%sedlex buf with
   | newline -> swallow_atmosphere buf
   | any -> swallow_comment buf
   | _ -> assert false

(** Return the next token. *)
let rec token buf =
   swallow_atmosphere buf;
   match%sedlex buf with
   | eof -> EOF

   | delimited_identifier ->
     Sedlexing.rollback buf;
     identifier buf

   | '(' -> LPAR
   | ')' -> RPAR

   | _ -> illegal buf (Char.chr (next buf))

and identifier buf =
   match%sedlex buf with
   | _ -> IDENTIFIER (Sedlexing.Utf8.lexeme buf)
```

(Yes, it's basically a no-op / the simplest thing possible rn. I'm trying to learn! `:x`)

Unfortunately, this combination results in an infinite loop in the parsing automaton:

```
State 0:
Lookahead token is now IDENTIFIER (1-1)
Shifting (IDENTIFIER) to state 1
State 1:
Lookahead token is now IDENTIFIER (1-1)
Reducing production expression -> IDENTIFIER 
State 5:
Shifting (IDENTIFIER) to state 1
State 1:
Lookahead token is now IDENTIFIER (1-1)
Reducing production expression -> IDENTIFIER 
State 5:
Shifting (IDENTIFIER) to state 1
State 1:
...
```

I'm new to parsing and lexing and all this; any advice would be welcome. I'm sure it's just a newbie mistake, but …

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried executing your code without the wrapper?

Comment: Also, as Sedlex gets the longest match, you really don't need your "match delimiter then rollback" (or your mutually recursive swallow) business.

Comment: @PatJ can you expand? And maybe make it an Answer, so I can give you points! `(=`

Comment: Well that's not the bug you're looking for, so it's not really worth an answer. I'll add info when I find your main error.

Comment: I wouldn't waste too much time — I took your implicit advice, and ripped the whole `rollback` bit out. I *am* curious how that resulted in an infinite parsing loop, but hey, I don't know if that mild interest is worth your time. `(=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said before, implementing too much logic inside the lexer is a bad idea.
However, the infinite loop does not come from the rollback but from your definition of `identifier`:

```
 identifier buf =
   match%sedlex buf with
   | _ -> IDENTIFIER (Sedlexing.Utf8.lexeme buf)
```

within this definition `_` matches the shortest possible words in the language consisting of all possible characters. In other words, `_` always matches the empty word μ without consuming any part of its input, sending the parser into an infinite loop.

Comment: Ahhah! Excellent spot! I guess I should have replaced that with the actual `identifier` regex. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How did I missed that? Nice one.